# Generating navigation from a datasource and linking dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, dom, sharepoint

I created a dynamic horizontal navigation that reads from a SharePoint list.  It works perfectly but I'm having an issue that's driving me crazy.  As my navigation items are getting rendered on the page, it's also linking each item until I get to an item that has drop-downs.  So for example, in this mockup [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/vYOJBxm) that uses an array of objects as its source, **Home**, **Site B**, **Site D** and **Site E** are clickable because I was able to make them links using the 'URL' property from my array of objects, but I am unable to make the following dropdowns clickable/linkable **Site A**, **Site C** and **Training** clickable

Here's an excerpt of the code that creates the links

```
function createNavigation(navData) {
    var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {
        if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
            var aLink = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
            aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
            aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
            topNav.appendChild(aLink);
        } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {
            var buildSubNavigation;
            
buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].id);
            topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
        } else {
            //build megamenu
            var buildSubNavigation;
            buildDirectorateNav = buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navData[x].id);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.  I tried modifying the function above and came close but them my horizontal navigation lost its style a little.  Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/oNxzxYK?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified CSS:

```
 .Mdropdown .Mdropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;  
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      
      background-color: inherit;
      font: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 17px;    
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      
    }
```

New CSS:

```
.fa{
    padding-top: 14px;
}
```